# Error: Expected an order id to be passed\n Laravel paypal integration

Tags: javascript, paypal

This is my js code ->

```js
paypal
    .Buttons({
        createOrder: function () {
            return fetch("/g/o/i/p", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                },
            })
                .then(function (res) {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return data.id; // Use the key sent by your server's response, ex. 'id' or 'token'
                });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                alert(
                    "Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name
                );
            });
        },
    })
    .render("#paypal-button-container"); // Display payment options on your web page
```

This is the console.log(data) ->

[This shows the order got created successfully and it has the id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkcPj.png)

The error ->
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pPQw.png)

Comment: That JS looks correct, but can you try with the newest sample from https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server -- (which also includes error handling for the capture step, good to have)

Comment: But in the onApprove function it makes a request to what?

Comment: You need two server routes, one for the creation and one for the capture. Do *not* mix a server-side create with a client-side `actions.order.capture()`.

Comment: So i need to find that order that was created and send it back?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem actually i needed to return the id of the order but the `data.id` was returning undefined because that should be `data.result.id`.

Comment: Your server must be responding with a full request object (serialized as JSON) rather than just a body as would be more normal. You should probably change what's being sent from the server end so that `data.id` works

Comment: Yes i understand but i actually dont need it so i went for data.result.id